# Pro*C++ compiler is not able to identify my header file

Tags: c++, oracle, redhat, proc

I am trying to compile a proc file  on redhat server.
It seems Pro*C++ compiler is not able to open my header file.
It give me the follow errors :
`Error at line 14, column 10 in file ../proc/myproc.pc
    #include "myproc.h"
    .........1
    PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file`

the myproc.h is the same directory with myproc.pc.
Any ideas please to solve this issue? Thank you very much

Comment: But from where you run this? Try to run from `proc` directory

Answer (score 0):

You are try to compile the code from outside your `proc`directory.

Use the `INCLUDE=../proc` as command line parameter while building or include the same in your `gmake` file